# How to delete versions without having column name in sharepoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, versioning, wss

In version history i am getting some duplicate versions with out any field changed....So for those versions the column name will be empty. Programmatically i would like to delete the versions in the version history where no column name specified...
Please help..

[image: Version History]
In the image you can see the blank versions...I need to remove those versions

Answer (score 3):

The code below deletes versions from the list item. You can re-use it and add the condition of checking the name as empty.

///

```
    /// Removes unneeded versions from a sharepoint list item

    /// </summary>

    /// <param name="item">The SPListItem that needs some versions removed</param>

    /// <param name="minVersions">The minimum number of versions to keep</param>

    /// <param name="savedVersions">A collection of important version labels (or null)</param>

    /// <returns>The number of versions deleted</returns>

    internal static int RemoveVersions(SPListItem item, int minVersions, ICollection<string> savedVersions)

    {

        //  Homework for the reader: validate the input arguments.

        //  if item is null, throw an ArgumentNullException

        //  if minVersions < 0 throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException



        int deletedCount = 0;

        int i = minVersions;    // start looking for old versions after skipping minVersions



        while (i < item.Versions.Count)

        {

            SPListItemVersion itemVersion = item.Versions[i];

            string versionLabel = itemVersion.VersionLabel;



            if (!itemVersion.IsCurrentVersion &&    // Not "current" according to SharePoint (e.g. last-published major version, moderated version)

                (savedVersions == null || !savedVersions.Contains(versionLabel)))  // not one of our "saved" versions

            {

                itemVersion.Delete();

                ++deletedCount;

            }

            else

            {

                ++i;

            }

        }



        return deletedCount;

    }
```