# Editing Sharepoint list item versions

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a custom list with a text field that set to append changes to the field.  This uses versioning.  The problem I have is that existing entries have been duplicated in versions.  I'd like to go and clean up these programatically, but I don't see a way to pull this.  The client object model gives me access to the list item, but there are no methods that I see there to even read past versions, let alone edit them.  Or is this something that can only be done server side?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144633/how-to-delete-versions-without-having-column-name-in-sharepoint-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer I was looking for at [How to delete versions without having column name in sharepoint list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144633/how-to-delete-versions-without-having-column-name-in-sharepoint-list) - It looks like it is not possible through the client model, only server side.